# Python3 subprocess.run with aws, not escaping spaces

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, subprocess

So I'm writing a python script that loops through a list with two file names that are in the same directory. Then the script uses `os.path.join()` to get the absolute path of this file.

The code I use is this:

```
for i in ["my filename with spaces 1.txt", "my filename with spaces 2.txt"]:
    path = os.path.join(cwd, "testing", i)

    subprocess.run("aws s3 cp " + path + " s3://" + selectedEnv + "-pathname/to/folder, shell=True)
```

The issue is that the script runs, but something about the spaces in my filenames causes the aws cli to return `Unknown options: "with", "spaces"...` and so on. I've tried escaping the spaces with the back tick `, backslashes \ and carets ^, none of which fix the issue.

My terminal is currently Windows Powershell, but I'm trying to ensure that this python script can run on both linux and powershelll command lines.

Comment: Add quotation marks: `"aws s3 cp '" + path + "' s3://"`

Comment: While using embedded quoting for `path` is indeed needed, the embedded quotes must be _double_ quotes: `subprocess.run("aws s3 cp \"" + path + "\" s3://" + selectedEnv + "-pathname/to/folder, shell=True)`

Comment: Curious, when you tried escaping the spaces with \, did you also prefix the strings with `r` to make them raw string literals? e.g. `r"my\ filename\ with\ spaces\ 1.txt"`